# Spring.Net Quartz scheduling and code config

Tags: spring.net, quartz.net, spring.codeconfig

Is there a way to configure Quartz scheduling (Spring.Scheduling.Quartz) in Spring.Net using code config rather than xml files?

I want to completely avoid using config files when setting up Quartz jobs with Spring.Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample that uses both programmatic and XML based job scheduling glued together with CodeConfig.

```cs
[Definition]
public virtual IScheduler Scheduler()
{
    var scheduler = SchedulerFactory().GetScheduler();
    var dataCleanUpJob = JobBuilder.Create<DataCleanUpJob>()
        .WithIdentity("DataCleanUpJob", "System")
        .StoreDurably(true)
        .Build();

    ITrigger dataCleanUpTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInHours(1)).Build();
    scheduler.ScheduleJob(dataCleanUpJob, dataCleanUpTrigger);

    scheduler.StartDelayed(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    return scheduler;
}

[Definition]
public virtual ISchedulerFactory SchedulerFactory()
{
    var properties = new NameValueCollection();

    // job initialization plugin handles our xml reading, without it defaults are used
    properties["quartz.plugin.xml.type"] = "Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin, Quartz";
    properties["quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames"] = "~/quartz_jobs.config";

    var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
    return factory;
}
```

Key points here are to have singleton for scheduler factory and the actual scheduler so they will be available from Spring context.

Comment: Thanks Marko but this seems to still require an xml config file which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You don't need if you just schedule jobs like in scheduler method. The XML config was just an example if there's a need to change job/trigger configuration without recompiling.